# Lua: problems when using parameters to reference table values

Tags: function, parameters, lua

I'm missing something fundamental when it comes to parameters.

```
obj = {
    name = "hey"
}
function say_name(p,k)
    return p.k
end

print(say_name(obj,name))  --doesn't print "hey"
```

I don't understand why this isn't giving the same output as print(obj.name) i.e. "hey"
Changing the function yields the following cases:

```
function say_name(p) --works...makes sense to me
    return p.name
end
function say_name(p,k) --doesn't work...why does k not work the same as p?
    return p.k
end
function say_name(p,name) --works....why tho? isn't name a parameter like k is..?
    return p.name
end
```

Is it cause I'm referencing a table value with a parameter? Is there some rule to this I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try this:

obj = {
    name = "hey"
}
function say_name(p,k)
    return p[k]
end

print(say_name(obj,"name"))
```

I added quotes around `name`. `name` is `nil`, but you need the string `"name"` to index `obj.name` or `obj["name"]` respectively

`p.k` is equivalent to `p["k"]` ! This only works for string keys that are valid Lua names. If you have a variable or any other key you need to use the square bracket notation.

From the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual - 3.2 Variables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.2)

> Square brackets are used to index a table:
>
> ```
>  var ::= prefixexp ‘[’ exp ‘]’
> ```
>
> The meaning of accesses to table fields can be changed via metatables
> (see §2.4).
>
> The syntax var.Name is just syntactic sugar for var["Name"]:
>
> ```
>  var ::= prefixexp ‘.’ Name
> ```

---

> ```
> function say_name(p,k) --doesn't work...why does k not work the same as p?
>     return p.k
> end
> ```

`p.k` is `p["k"]`. It has nothing to do with the parameter `k` of your function

> ```
> function say_name(p,name) --works....why tho? isn't name a parameter like k is..?
>     return p.name
> end
> ```

`p.name` is `p["name"]`. It has nothing to do with your parameter `name`. It's just a conincidence that it works for `obj.name` because `obj` has a field `"name"`, any other string wouldn't work

Comment: I get the same problem with the code change u made. i.e. [nil]

Comment: sorry forgot the quotes. it's `sayname(obj, "name")`